# Angular testing - cannot run assertion inside subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test a service which has a method which returns an observable, but I keep getting this error when running a `expect` inside `subscribe`

> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

I tried to increase the timeout interval for Jasmine, but this didn't work. Here is my code:

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  subject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() { }

  sendUserNotification(message: string): void {
    this.subject.next(message);
  }

  getUserNotification(): Observable<string> {
      return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

user.service.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(UserService);
  });

  it('should be able to set and get the registered user', (done) => {
    service.sendUserNotification('testNotification');
    service.getUserNotification().subscribe((notification: string): void => {
      expect(notification).toEqual('testNotification1');   //  This is causing the error
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Please advise what could be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are doing the call in the wrong order.

Because you are dispatching the event and then subscribing, when in fact, you should subscribe first and then dispatch the event.

On resume, in your spec file you need to do:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(UserService);
  });

  it('should be able to set and get the registered user', (done) => {
    service.getUserNotification().subscribe((notification) => {
      expect(notification).toEqual('testNotification1');
      done();
    });
    service.sendUserNotification('testNotification');
  });
});
```

Comment: Your welcome. 
Also, another improvement that you can do is instead of having the method ```getUserNotification()```  returning ```this.subject.asObservable();``` every time you want to subscribe to the subject, you can create a public property like this one: ```userNotification$ : Observable< string > = this.subject.asObservable()```, there you will call only once to ```this.subject.asObservable();```